# Suspend not working in Ubuntu 22.04.01

Tags: suspend, acpi, systemd-logind, pm-utils

I use Ubuntu 22.04.01 on a dual booted HP machine. Since the last week, suspend is not working. Everytime I close the lid, or suspend it using the gui option my laptop shuts down. Tried using `pm-utils suspend` but that shuts down the machine as well.
I checked the `/etc/systemd/loind.conf` file as well and uncommented the lines `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`,
`HandleSuspendKey=suspend` and
`HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend`.
Sleep works fine when I'm booted into my windows 10 environment, but doesn't on linux. So this lead me to believe that there's no problem with the hardware and bios. So I got tired of trying to look for the problem and reinstalled ubuntu from scratch. But for some reason that did nothing to the suspend situation at all! My laptop still shuts down if I suspend it. I can't figure out what the problem is. Please help me!!